# Populating an NSMutableArray from a NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I have this string:

```
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:groupPath];
```

...which has this content (from the path):

a, b, c, d,

...how can I populate the array with the above objects??

I tried:

```
 self.itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[itemArray initWithObjects:fileContent, nil];
```

...the aim is to get:

```
[itemArray initWithObjects:a, b, c, d, nil];
```

Comment: Can't understand, why -2? this wasn't a good question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is delimited with `", "`, the [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) method in `NSString` is what you want. So you'd have something like:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]];
self.itemArray = array;
[array release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string by ", " and create a mutable copy of that array.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly please? In the groupPath there is a file which has written in it "a, b, c, d,", so how can I separate them?

Comment: You read the content of your file into a string. You can split that string by [fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was this function